# List of missing records for reverse OneOnOneField in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models with the same primary key:

```
class OperationalDevice(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(primary_key=True)
    mac = models.CharField()

class AllowedDevice(models.Model):
    ip = models.OneToOneField(OperationalDevice, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint=False, db_column='ip')
    type = models.CharField()
    owner = models.CharField()
```

I would like to display the list of all AllowedDevices that are down - kind of like:

```
SELECT AllowedDevice.ip from AllowedDevice
LEFT OUTER JOIN OperationalDevice ON
     AllowedDevice.ip = OperationalDevice.ip
WHERE OperationalDevice.ip is NULL
```

I tried using `AllowedDevice.objects.filter(ip__...)`, but it creates `inner join`. I also tried `objects.exclude` and `objects.annotate`, and they also create a query with `inner join`

Maybe I should't be using OneToOneField?

Making the relationship go the other way is not a solution, because I need to find both kinds of exceptions - devices that are in one table but not the other.

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655526):

> I have two tables with the same primary key.
>
> ```
> ip            mac
> 11.11.11.11   48-C0-09-1F-9B-54
> 33.33.33.33   4E-10-A3-BC-B8-9D
> 44.44.44.44   CD-00-60-08-56-2A
> 55.55.55.55   23-CE-D3-B1-39-A6
>
> ip            type     owner
> 22.22.22.22   laptop   John Doe
> 33.33.33.33   server   XYZ Department
> 44.44.44.44   VM       Mary Smith
> 66.66.66.66   printer  ZWV Department
> ```
>
> The first table is automatically refreshed every minute. I can't
>   change the database structure or the script that populates it.
>
> Both tables have `ip` as PRIMARY KEY.
>
> In a view, I would like to display a table like this:
>
> ```
> ip           mac               type    owner          Alert
> 11.11.11.11  48-C0-09-1F-9B-54                        Unauthorized
> 55.55.55.55  23-CE-D3-B1-39-A6                        Unauthorized
> 22.22.22.22                    laptop  John Doe       Down
> 66.66.66.66                    printer ZWV Department Down
> 33.33.33.33  4E-10-A3-BC-B8-9D server  XYZ Department OK
> 44.44.44.44  CD-00-60-08-56-2A VM      Mary Smith     OK
> ```
>
> How can I model this? Should I make one of the two primary keys a
>   foreign key into the other one?
>
> Once the code is in operation, there will be lots of data, so I want
>   to make sure it's fast enough.
>
> What is the fastest way to retrieve the data?

Comment: The required `on_delete` parameter is missing from your relationship definition. If it is `SET_NULL`, then you cannot use the one-to-one field as a primary key. If it is `CASCADE`, then your `AllowedDevices` will be deleted when an `OperationalDevice` goes down, making this question moot.

Comment: I have `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`.

Comment: Django can be persuaded to use left joins with one-to-many relations, but apparently not with one-to-one.

Comment: @EndreBoth - but it doesn't make sense to use **one-to-many** if they are both unique fields.

Comment: Sure, that was not my implication.

Comment: @EndreBoth - I thought you were suggesting me to try `one-to-many`

Answer (score 0):

To use left outer join you should use `.values('one_to_one_field__sub_filed')` or `.annotate(sub_field=F('one_to_one_field__sub_filed'))`:

```py
from django.db.models import F
AllowedDevice.objects.all().annotate(mac=F('ip__mac'))
```

But I think that you really need a "FULL JOIN" that can only be simulated using `QS.union()`. See the last part (Using OneToOneField for better SQL) of [answer to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55976564/952437) for details.